# How is frequent itemsets compared with item-based collaborative filtering in recommender systems?

Tags: data-mining, collaborative-filtering

What is the difference between data mining approaches: frequent itemsets and item-based collaborative filtering in the area of recommender systems?

Comment: Cross-posted to: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5644/how-is-frequent-itemsets-compared-with-item-based-collaborative-filtering-in-rec

Comment: Apples and Bananas. Both are fruit.

Answer (score 0):

Frequent itemsets use only unary data: we know that a person has certain items in her basket but we have no idea if she knows other items in the universe exist. That is, does she not have item Z in her basket because she knows about it and doesn't like it, or because she doesn't know about it (and might have included it if she did).

Item-based collaborative filtering, on the other hand, most often includes rating data. E.g., star ratings on a scale of 0.5 to 5.0 (in the case of MovieLens). Here we can better calculate the similarity between items because we have both positive and negative opinions, and we can make a much more informed guess that if a user doesn't rate an item, she doesn't know it exists.